# "X rode Y to school" - is this grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, syntax

This question is based on https://www.learncbse.in/ncert-solutions-for-class-2-english-chapter-2. To summarize, Haldi is a girl who got  lift from Smiley (a giraffe) to her school. Now, is the sentence "Haldi rode Smiley to school" correct?

Comment: To get ***a*** lift is to get a ride (as in In a vehicle)  The driver gives you a lift.  If I heard that Smiley gave Haldi a lift to school, I’d picture Smiley driving a car.  When I learn that Smiley is a giraffe, I’d picture a children’s book and a sunroof.  Having said that, Haldi rode Smiley to school is perfectly fine if Haldi climbed on Smiley’s back and rode him like a horse.

Comment: agreed, my wording in the question is ambiguous - shouldnt have used the word "lift".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The manner in which Haldi was given the lift (an assisted journey) by Smiley was that Haldi rode Smiley. Constructs such as "He rides a horse" or "she rode a bicycle" are in common usage and this example with a giraffe is no different. It is clear, unambiguous and correct.